# Email issue with Laravel 5.1 after Mail-in-a-box upgrade

Tags: laravel, email, ssl

I am using Laravel 5.1 for a project and the mail feature used to work properly until recently. I am getting the following error when I try sending email using Laravel.

Has anyone had the same problem?

- Laravel version: 5.1
- PHP version: 7.1
- Mail server: Mail-in-a-box
  v0.46

**Error message:**

local.ERROR: ErrorException: stream_socket_enable_crypto(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:1409442E:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:tlsv1 alert protocol version

I believe it is the 'SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:tlsv1 alert protocol version' section which describes the problem.

Below is the contents of my *.env* file.
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=<MY_MAIL_HOST>
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=<MY_USERNAME>
MAIL_PASSWORD=<MY_PASSWORD>
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
MAIL_PRETEND=false

Comment: what email host you use? is your own server or google

Comment: Yes, it is my own server with Mail-in-a-box V0.46. I was reading that it might be the Swiftmailer (I have v5.4 something -- the one which comes with Laravel 5.1) and it doesn't support the TLSv1.1 and further.

Comment: Actually, it used to work until recently when I upgraded the Main-in-a-box version.

Comment: You give few details on the version you upgraded from, but the only [change in .46](https://github.com/mail-in-a-box/mailinabox/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md#v046-june-11-2020) was an upgrade of the Roundcube version. However, if your version was older than .44, you may want to [review those changes](https://github.com/mail-in-a-box/mailinabox/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md#v044-february-15-2020).